# What are View Coordinates?

Tags: 3d-view, coordinates

I was reading a wikibook about Blender, and it started talking about view coordinates. I don't exactly understand what they are or the purpose of their existence.

Could someone please explain them in a newbie friendly fashion?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you switch to View space Coordinates, all transformations depend on the view; So the x axis is horizontal and y is vertical; If you move your view, so move the axis.

It's useful if you only want to move a particular object relative to the view.

To lock a transform to any axis, while in View transform orientation, press the respective axis key twice; So to lock translate to the View's X axis, press <kbd>G</kbd> <kbd>X</kbd> <kbd>X</kbd>.